# How to set up Nginx to unify Django + React application?

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx

I've done Django + React application. The backend and frontend servers will run on their own ports. I want to set up Nginx to unify both development servers. How can combine this two server using ngnix?

Comment: does reactjs need a server?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean.